# How to use curl (or similar software) with "docker run" if ENTRYPOINT already used?

Tags: docker, curl, aiohttp

I want to create docker image with `Tor`/`aiohttp` server to use as a proxy for HTTP requests (`curl` mostly). I've already prepared working Docker image (I can use external `curl -x` with it), the main problem with syntax.

**What I need:** I need to use this image like `docker run test_image curl api.ipify.org`. Main problem - I don't understand how to configure ENTRYPOINT/CMD correctly. I use `supervisor` to activate services (tor/aiohttp), so the last line of my Docker image is:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]`

**Question:** How can I configure Docker image (using ENTRYPOINT/CMD), so the image will run my curl request after activating services?

With current exec entrypoint (or shell form) it ignores curl. If I use cmd instead of entrypoint, curl works, but image ignores cmd, so services are not activated.

So need any advice about Docker logic/syntax, so I can make it work.

Comment: Why is it important to run curl from within the container?  Why is it important for the container to be running multiple services?

Comment: It's an academic task with straight conditions. I have no problems with curl or running services, main question - how can I combine ENTRYPOINT with some external software (curl, or ping, or tracert, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run **ENTRYPOINT** as a shell script instead of a command:

https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data

docker-entrpoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
curl api.ipify.org
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stretch
...
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: It works, but I need to use curl from "docker run", so I can specify url and so on from CLI. I can use env variables, of course, but, because of conditions, need to work with curl (or other software) from "docker run test_image curl http://someurl.com".

Comment: You can override the ENTRYPOINT at run time, but we're starting to break some Docker principals: `docker run --rm -it  --entrypoint "curl http://google.com" test_image`

Comment: docker run test_image 'curl someurl.com' - no use

Comment: You can override the ENTRYPOINT at run time - I can, still I need to start services before using curl, so it can use service sockets as proxy.

Comment: No need to run curl WITH container, curl was on a new line, when I thought it was on the same :)